# iOS 6.0: UICollectionView doesn't respect clipsToBounds with pagingEnabled

Tags: objective-c, ios6

**Background**

I am implementing a `UICollectionView` (for the first time) in an effort to achieve a paged horizontal scroll view of tiles.  I'd like each tile to show in the center of the frame with it's sister tiles partially visible to the left and right (something like the page selector in the Safari app).  I'm interested in using the `UICollectionView` to take advantage of built-in cell dequeueing and would rather not use a rotated `UITableView`.

**Issue**

The issue I'm finding is that when using `pagingEnabled = YES` and `clipsToBounds = NO`, the `UICollectionView` removes cells outside the `collectionView` frame (they're not in the `visibleCells` array) as soon as paging is complete.  Can anyone provide advice on how to achieve the effect of displaying previews of the sister tiles while maintaining this basic setup? Or am I approaching this incorrectly?

**Screenshots**

*start*
[image: start]
*scrolling*
[image: scrolling]
*end*
[image: end]

The **scrolling** screen is exactly correct.  But in the start and end shots I want there to be green visible in the blue margins.

Here's what's in my AppDelegate.m (credit to [tutsplus.com](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uicollectionview-layouts) for the basic setup here):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController : UICollectionViewController
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ID"];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    // pad the collection view by 20 px
    UIEdgeInsets padding = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0);
    [self.collectionView setFrame:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.view.frame, padding)];
    // set pagingEnabled and clipsToBounds off
    [self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [self.collectionView setClipsToBounds:NO];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    return cell;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
{
    ViewController *vc;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // setup the UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(280, 280);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    // add a custom UICollectionViewController to the window
    vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out the solution to this was actually quite simple.  I just needed to overlap the `UICollectionViewCell` cells by enough pixels to have them still show within the collectionView's frame after the paged scrolling finishes.  The relevent code was

```
layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(300, 300);
layout.minimumLineSpacing = -20.0;
```

And I subclassed the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and overrode the `(CGSize)collectionViewContentSize` method to return the non-overlapped size of the cells.

Comment: We found that this works until you have 6 or more cells, at which point cells start disappearing even if they are inside view frame. It happens when the cell in question is *behind* both neighbour cells (this is where we stopped investigating).

Comment: I can't make this work on iOS 8, on the new iPhone sizes, and supporting Autolayout.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks for the tip about using a negative minimumLineSpacing. I created a tester application which uses a collection view cell loaded from a xib file. The cell has a transparent background and an “inner” view for the cell's content.

In this way, a custom flow layout is not necessary.

https://github.com/j4johnfox/CollectionViewTester

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in collectionView, but it could be possibly do with this line in cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:label];
```

Everytime it's called, another label subview is added to cell. Either check for an existing label or subclass UICollectionViewCell?

Comment: Thanks! Commenting that out doesn't affect the clipping area at all so doesn't solve the core issue, but good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to also override `-pointInside:withEvent:` to allow scroll gestures to start outside the frame of the collection view. I do this using a `UIEdgeInsets` property in my collection view subclass:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGRect extendedBounds = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, self.touchAreaInsets);

    return CGRectContainsPoint(extendedBounds, point);
}
```

If you don't need App Store safety, you can override `_visibleBounds` to avoid negative spacing hacks:

```
- (CGRect)_visibleBounds {
     return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(self.bounds, self.touchAreaInsets);
}
```

If you're not too pressed on code size and need App Store safety you could also subclass [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) and possibly override `visibleBoundRects` for the same effect.