# UICollectionView: paging like Safari tabs or App Store search

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview

I want to implement "cards" in my app like Safari tabs or App Store search.

I will show user one card in a center of screen and part of previous and next cards at left and right sides. (See App Store search or Safari tabs for example)

I decided to use `UICollectionView`, and I need to change page size (didn't find how) or implement own layout subclass (don't know how)?

Any help, please?

Answer (score 26):

Below is the simplest way that I've found to get this effect. It involves your collection view and an extra secret scroll view.

**Set up your collection views**

- Set up your collection view and all its data source methods.
- Frame the collection view; it should span the full width that you want to be visible.
- Set the collection view's `contentInset`:

  ```
  _collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.width-pageSize)/2, 0, (self.view.frame.size.width-pageSize)/2);
  ```

This helps offset the cells properly.

**Set up your secret scrollview**

- Create a scrollview, place it wherever you like. You can set it to `hidden` if you like.
- Set the size of the scrollview's bounds to the desired size of your page.
- Set yourself as the delegate of the scrollview.
- Set its `contentSize` to the expected content size of your collection view.

**Move your gesture recognizer**

- Add the secret scrollview's gesture recognizer to the collection view, and disable the collection view's gesture recognizer:

  ```
  [_collectionView addGestureRecognizer:_secretScrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
  _collectionView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
  ```

**Delegate**

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    contentOffset.x = contentOffset.x - _collectionView.contentInset.left;
    _collectionView.contentOffset = contentOffset;
}
```

As the scrollview moves, get its offset and set it to the offset of the collection view.

I blogged about this here, so check this link for updates: http://khanlou.com/2013/04/paging-a-overflowing-collection-view/

Comment: This, however, does not pass select and tap events correctly through to the underlying collection view as of iOS7. Any ideas?

Comment: On iOS7 (at least— might have been true before this) you don't need the scrollview. Just detect left and right swipe gestures and use them to set the offset of your collection view 1 page forward/back.

Comment: I can't for the life of me get it to work on iOS7. `scrollViewDidScroll` of a "secret" scroll view are never delivered.

Comment: Make sure your view controller conforms to the UIScrollView delegate protocol and set it as the 'secret' scroll view's delegate.

Comment: Works for me in iOS 7.  The directions are a bit confusing but it's actually straight forward.  Tap events also appear to work as well.

Comment: @ThomasVerbeek My controller definitely conforms, but the scroll events are delivered from the collection view, **not** secret scroll view (as implied in the linked blog post). Definitely no paging going on.

Comment: Alternative solution that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14485014/23643 + http://stackoverflow.com/q/3735218/23643

Comment: Finally. I have revisited this solution, and it turns out the problem is with dynamic content. Collection view `contentSize` is not properly updated after `reloadData`, so width was always 0 when view initially loads. As a workaround (which I don't completely understand yet), I used `_collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize` instead of `_collectionView.contentSize` to update secret scroll view's content size. http://stackoverflow.com/q/19103333/23643

Comment: We got this working on iOS 7. However, we found that on the iPhone 5s (strangely, only that device), we had to add the scrollview to the current view, and send it to the back. This is with hidden=YES and pagingEnabled=YES.

Answer (score 6):

You can subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and override like so:

```
- (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset 
                                 withScrollingVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
{
    NSArray* layoutAttributesArray = 
   [self layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:self.collectionView.bounds];

    if(layoutAttributesArray.count == 0)
        return contentOffset;


    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* candidate = 
    layoutAttributesArray.firstObject;

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* layoutAttributes in layoutAttributesArray)
    {
        if (layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory != UICollectionElementCategoryCell)
            continue;


        if((velocity.x > 0.0 && layoutAttributes.center.x > candidate.center.x) ||
           (velocity.x <= 0.0 && layoutAttributes.center.x < candidate.center.x))
            candidate = layoutAttributes;


    }

    return CGPointMake(candidate.center.x - self.collectionView.bounds.size.width * 0.5f, contentOffset.y);
}
```

This will get the next or previous cell depending on the velocity... it will not snap on the current cell however.

Comment: Returning a different `CGPoint` for the offset through this delegate method works quite well. The transition to stop on the cell feels quite smooth.

Comment: Also, it seems like the trick to getting the scroll view to *snap* when transitioning is to set the collection view's `decelerationRate` to `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast`. For faster snapping, it also seems like it kinda works if you set the `decelerationRate` to something smaller than 0.990000 (which seems to be the current `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast`).

Answer (score 2):

[@Mike M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22454509/123632) in Swift…

```
class CenteringFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        guard let collectionView = collectionView,
            let layoutAttributesArray = layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(collectionView.bounds),
            var candidate = layoutAttributesArray.first else { return proposedContentOffset }

        layoutAttributesArray.filter({$0.representedElementCategory == .Cell }).forEach { layoutAttributes in

            if (velocity.x > 0 && layoutAttributes.center.x > candidate.center.x) ||
                (velocity.x <= 0 && layoutAttributes.center.x < candidate.center.x) {
                candidate = layoutAttributes
            }
        }

        return CGPoint(x: candidate.center.x - collectionView.bounds.width / 2, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little edit on Soroush answer, which did the trick for me. 
The only edit I made instead of disabling the gesture:

```
[_collectionView addGestureRecognizer:_secretScrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
_collectionView.panGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

I disabled scrolling on the collectionview:

```
_collectionView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

As disabling the gesture disabled the secret scrollview gesture as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another solution. The snapping in place is not perfect (not as good as when paging enabled is set, but works well enough).

I have tried implementing Soroush's solution, but it doesn't work for me.

Because the `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` it will respond to an important `UIScrollViewDelegate` method which is:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

The `targetContentOffset` (an **inout pointer**) lets you redefine the stopping point for a collection view (the `x` in this case if you swipe horizontally).

A quick note about a couple of the variables found below:

- `self.cellWidth` – this is your collection view cell's width (you can even hardcode it there if you want)
- `self.minimumLineSpacing` – this is the minimum line spacing you set between the cells
- `self.scrollingObjects` is the array of objects contained in the collection view (I need this mostly for the count, to know when to stop scrolling)

So, the idea is to implement this method in the collection view's delegate, like so:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                     withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
              targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{       
    if (self.currentIndex == 0 && velocity.x < 0) {
        // we have reached the first user and we're trying to go back
        return;
    }

    if (self.currentIndex == (self.scrollingObjects.count - 1) && velocity.x > 0) {
        // we have reached the last user and we're trying to go forward
        return;
    }

    if (velocity.x < 0) {
        // swiping from left to right (going left; going back)
        self.currentIndex--;
    } else {
        // swiping from right to left (going right; going forward)
        self.currentIndex++;
    }

    float xPositionToStop = 0;

    if (self.currentIndex == 0) {
        // first row
        xPositionToStop = 0;
    } else {
        // one of the next ones
        xPositionToStop = self.currentIndex * self.cellWidth + (self.currentIndex + 1) * self.minimumLineSpacing - ((scrollView.bounds.size.width - 2*self.minimumLineSpacing - self.cellWidth)/2);
    }

    targetContentOffset->x = xPositionToStop;

    NSLog(@"Point of stopping: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(*targetContentOffset));
}
```

Looking forward to any feedback you may have which makes the snapping in place better. I'll also keep on looking for a better solution...

Comment: This seems to work... but doesn't replicate "paging enabled" precisely and feels a bit awkward.

Answer (score -6):

The previous is quite complicated, UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so just do this：

```
[self.collectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

You are all set to go.

See this [detailed tutorial](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/04/creating-a-paged-photo-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/).

Comment: This doesn't address the issue with having content on the left and right visible while paging, like the safari tabs or app store search.